# External configuration in Spring Boot and one-off testing

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

Spring boot has an ability to [externalize](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) the configuration, which means `you can work with the same application code in different environments`.

> You can bundle an application.properties inside your jar that provides
>   a sensible default name. When running in production, an
>   application.properties can be provided outside of your jar that
>   overrides name; and for one-off testing, you can launch with a
>   specific command line switch:

```
java -jar app.jar --name="Spring"
```

1. What does one-off testing actually mean?
2. How can I `work with the same application code in different environments`?

Comment: *one-off* means "only once" or in this case a config, that you want to check or test, but is not for eternity.  and what do you mean by "how can i".  the docs allready explains it.  you build one jar and use e.g. [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) to adjust it to the environment where it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the second question! But what does --name refer to? Is Spring a name of the property in app.properties ?

Comment: look at the code example above the line you quoted in your question.  there is an annotation `@Value("${name}")` for a variable.  this is filled by default from the props.  you can override the props on commandline with `--name` in that case.  this is a rather synthetic example.  but e.t. `--server.port=9080` overrides `server.port` from props and is a lot more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One-off testing**

I find that usually in the context of Spring Boot, the 'one-off testing' referred to tends to be about switching the active profile. For instance, when I run up my applications locally, I usually use this command:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=scratch
```

That activates my 'scratch' profile which sets up an in-memory database and imports some base test data into it. I have a little `run.sh` script which I check in to Git, which includes that.

That's the profile I want activated when I'm playing around on my local machine. However, for occasional **one-off tests**, I may wish to run up my application against a more permanent database. To do that I just need to tweak the active profile in my command line, like so...

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=sqlserver
```

This activates the `application-sqlserver.properties` file in my config directory and sets up a locally running Spring Boot application backed by a SQL Server database. It's a one-off because I don't intend to use it as the default build database connection.

**Running the same application code in different environments**

This provides the foundation for using "the same application code in different environments". Assuming that you have built a sample Spring Boot application, you should have noticed that the build creates a single `.jar` file. The idea is that this same `.jar` file will be deployed to all environments. This is a **good thing** because if you have tested your application in one environment and wish to promote to production, then surely you want to be confident that the code you are deploying is the same code you just tested?

However, obviously each of your environments has different requirements. When you are building, you may wish to use an in-memory database. However, in your integration test environments you will probably want to connect to a physical database such as MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server. You probably have separate test and production databases. Each environment may connect to different RabbitMQ clusters.

Spring Boot supports this by externalising configuration. It will automatically look for properties in a directory called `config` in the root of your application. i.e. You can create a directory structure like so...

```
myapp/
    config/
        application.properties
    myapp.jar
```

... and the only thing that needs to be different in each environment is `application.properties`, where you can point at different databases, LDAP directories, email systems, message brokers or whatever else is different in each environment.

**The `--name` argument**

As mentioned in the [Spring Boot documentation on accessing command line properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args), command line arguments starting with `--` are converted to a application properties. Therefore `--name` becomes a property that you can access within your application. It is worth noting that it is not a required argument for starting Spring Boot applications.

As a side note, `--name` is quite commonly used when starting up a 'NIX command line process so that you can `ps ax | grep Spring` and see your process. Usually so that you can kill it. It's not a required argument for Spring Boot apps, rather just something that's used in the example you refer to. That example refers to it via the `@Value("${name}")` annotation.